# Cannot get formControlName of FormBuilder Array

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I get an error in getting the `formControlName` of a `FormBuilder` Array:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'elements -> 0 -> name'

```
<form [formGroup]="targetAttributesForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
  <input formControlName="nono" placeholder="First">

  <div formArrayName="elements">
    <div *ngFor="let address of targetAttributesForm.controls.elements.controls; let w=index" class="panel panel-default">
      <div [formGroupName]="w">
        <span>Att {{w + 1}}</span>
        --> {{ address[w] }}
        <label>Attribut name</label><input type="text" formControlName="name">
        <label>Attribut type</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

my app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.targetAttributesForm = this._fb.group({
       nono : ['a', Validators.required],
       elements : this._fb.array([this.initAttribut]) 
      });
}
initAttribut() {
  return this._fb.group({
        name : ['a', [Validators.required]],
        type : ['b', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

This is my error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'elements -> 0 -> name'
>   Trace de la pile :
>   _throwError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:69949:11
>   setUpControl@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:69857:9
>   ../../..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I corrected your question: I simplified the title (be as concise as you can!); I used blockquotes for all the error messages; I also rewrote your sentences, removing all useless parts ("please help me!", or multiple question/interrogation marks, for example).

Comment: manu thanks Massimiliano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mistyped because forgot to call your `initAttribut` function:

```
this._fb.array([this.initAttribut()])
                               ^^^^^^
                        you need to call this function
```

Otherwise `FormBuilder` will create array of one `FormControl` instead of array of one `FormGroup`.

**[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-36u8g3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Can we use array of FormControl instead of FormGroup inside elements?

Comment: @Nitul It's up to you. You can if you want

Comment: I tried but not working, may be somthing missing from my side. I tried defining formControlName="w" and removed formGroupName.

Comment: @Nitul Can you prepare a small demo with stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vijzfy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html